# SUSE Linux terminal is not recognizing some characters like "&", "?", "/"

Tags: linux, curl, suse

when i run this in terminal

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/{id}/items?limit=100&offset=0 -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

with valid access_token it gives me this response.

```
If '-H' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary: 
command-not-found -H 
-bash: -H: command not found
```

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3.

Comment: You probably have to escape them: `curl https://xxxx\&yyyy` etc.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui..it worked for me...

I did this :

curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/{id}/items\?limit=100\&offset=0 -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these characters you mention have to be escaped to prevent them from being interpreted by bash.

So for example instead of:

```
curl https://www.example.com/r?v=1&w=2
```

You need to use:

```
curl https://www.example.com/r\?v=1\&w=2
                              ^^   ^^
```

In your case:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/\{id\}/items\?limit=100\&offset=0 -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token" 
                                     ^^  ^^      ^^         ^^
```